# Probability Problem: Find the probability Roy loses his job

Tags: probability

Melchester Rovers are playing a football tournament of $5$ matches.

The probabilities that they win, draw or lose a match are $\frac12$, $\frac16$ and $\frac13$ respectively.

These probabilities remain constant; the result of a match is independent of the results of other matches.

At the end of the tournament their coach Roy loses his job if they lose three consecutive matches, otherwise he does not lose his job.

Find the probability that Roy loses his job.

My attempt:

Ways for Roy to lose his job:

- $L,L,L,\neg{L},\neg{L}$
- $\neg{L},L,L,L,\neg{L}$
- $\neg{L},\neg{L},L,L,L$
- $L,L,L,L,\neg{L}$
- $\neg{L},L,L,L,L$
- $L,L,L,L,L$

For the first three cases which I collectively call Case A:

$$P(A)=3\left(\left(\frac13\right)^3\left(\frac12\right)^2+2\left(\frac13\right)^2\left(\frac12\right)^1\left(\frac16\right)^1+\left(\frac13\right)^2\left(\frac16\right)^2\right)$$

For the next 2 cases which I collectively call Case B:

$$P(B)=2\left(\left(\frac13\right)^4\left(\frac12\right)^1+\left(\frac13\right)^4\left(\frac16\right)^1\right)$$

The last case; Case C:

$$P(C)=\left(\frac13\right)^5$$

Adding all of these:

$$P(A \cup B \cup C)=\frac{17}{234}$$

However, this is not the correct answer.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Consider, e.g. L L L W L.

Comment: you do not need to differentiate the team is win or draw; just combine them as "not lose", with probability 2/3. Partition the favorable cases into 3 -  LLL**, NLLL*, *NLLL, where N is not lose and * is any outcome.

Comment: For curiosity, what is the correct answer?

Comment: I don't know, I'm sorry. I just know mine 'doesn't match'

Comment: Would that be just: LLLNL & LNLLL? @W.Schlieper

Comment: before posting the full formula, is it 7/81?

Comment: Hi, I do not know the answer. I just know it isnt mine. Please post your formula :)

Comment: You missed the cases $L, \lnot L, L, L, L$ and $L, L, L, \lnot L, L$, which account for the missing $4/243$ probability. (I assume the exponent $2$ in $\left(\frac13\right)^2$ in two terms of the formula for $P(A)$ was $3$ in your actual calculations, and the $234$ in the final answer was actually $243$.)

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be the event that matches 1,2,3 are lost, let $B$ be the event that matches 2,3,4 are lost and let $C$ be the event that matches 3,4,5 are lost.

Then you are asked to find $P(A\cup B\cup C)$ wich can be done using [inclusion/exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and symmetry:

$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=3P(A)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap C)$$

Also realize that $A\cap C=A\cap B\cap C$ and $P(A\cap B)=P(B\cap C)$, leading to:$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=3P(A)-2P(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Could you elaborate to get 7/81?

Comment: @anja.wlotrzewiszczykowycki It's your turn to solve. This is a perfectly good hint.

Comment: Yes, anja @probablyme is right when he says it's your turn ;).

Comment: I got 7/81, all you did was add LLL(L')L & L(L')LLL

Comment: I solved it otherwise.

Comment: $\frac7{81}$ is correct. It agrees with my answer.

Comment: yo how do I delete a question?

Comment: Under your question there are things like "share", "edit", "delete". Just press. Are you planning to delete *this* question? Why? Btw, beautiful second name!

Comment: No it wasn't for this question & thank you ;D Takes some time to type!

Answer (score 1):

If Roy's run of $3$ consecutive losses materialises on the 4th or 5th game,
it must be immediately preceded by a "not lost", hence $Pr = (\frac13)^3[1 + 2(\frac23)] = \frac{7}{81}$

[ Other results don't matter ]

*Further explanation*

With $\bullet$ indicating results that don't matter (i.e. could be any of  $W, L$ or $D$)  and $L'=$ *not lose* ($W$ or $D$), sequences with Roy losing job are:

$LLL\bullet\bullet\quad L'LLL\bullet\quad \bullet L'LLL$

Comment: Could you explain that again? I think I'm not seeing something? Thank you! :)

Comment: Further explanation has been added.

Comment: but why don't you just have: LLL∙∙, ∙LLL∙ & ∙∙LLL ?

Comment: What are the dots ? If they correspond to my $\bullet$ (W,L or D), a losing sequence of three ending , say, on 4th game obviously can't be LLLL. Remember, Roy loses the job as soon as 3 consecutive games are lost !

Comment: ..(contd) no matter what happens afterwards.